# Unable to use *build* object in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[The docs state that:](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/build)

> build can be specified either as a string containing a path to the
>   build context, or an object with the path specified under context and
>   optionally dockerfile and args.

So I crafted my docker-compose like this:

```
  1 mesh-node-web:
  2   container_name: mesh-node-web
  3   build:
  4     context: ./mesh-node-web
  5   ports:
  6     - '5000:5000'
  7     - '3000:3000'
```

But that returns

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
mesh-node-web.build contains an invalid type, it should be a string
```

What am I doing wrong? I'd like my docker-compose file to use 2 different Dockerfiles. One for back-end and one for front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

context is a version 2 syntax, and since you haven't defined the version inside your compose file, it defaults to the version 1 syntax. Therefore, you can only pass the directory as the value of build.

Answer (score 0):

`context` is not required.

This works:

```
  1 mesh-node-web:
  2   container_name: mesh-node-web
  3   build: ./mesh-node-web
  4   ports:
  5     - '5000:5000'
  6     - '3000:3000'
```